# How to set up Super+comma shortcut in PhpStorm, Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, hotkeys, ubuntu-18.04

PhpStorm, Ubuntu 18.04

I am trying to set hotkeys to my liking. I am unable to register pressing <kbd>Super</kbd> key along with any other key. What happens is that only second keystroke is remembered as if <kbd>Super</kbd> key was not treated as modifier key.

What's more, when I press only a <kbd>Super</kbd> key I see <kbd>Windows</kbd> being registered by PhpStorm.

How can I use hotkeys like e.g. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>comma</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>?

Comment: Doesn't <kbd>windows</kbd> and <kbd>super</kbd> act the same on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Ástþór Maybe. I found it peculiar so maybe it somehow adds to the problem. Maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using `GNOME Tweaks` program.

Under `Keyboard & Mouse`-><kbd>Additional Layout Options</kbd>->`Alt/Win key behavior` I selected **Meta is mapped to Win**.

Now I can use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>comma</kbd> as well as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in PhpStorm.